# Laravel DB query for REST API very slow

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, mariadb

I'm doing my first steps with Laravel and try to write a music playlist. The database has 3 entities/models:

```
Play <-n-1-> Song <-n-1-> Artist
```

Tables creation:

```php
        Schema::create('plays', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->bigInteger('song_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('song_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('songs')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->dateTimeTz('date');
            $table->bigInteger('station_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('station_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('stations');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->unique(['song_id', 'date']);
        });

        Schema::create('songs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->bigInteger('artist_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('artist_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('artists')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('cover_url')->nullable();
            $table->smallInteger('cover_width')->nullable();
            $table->smallInteger('cover_height')->nullable();
            $table->string('asin')->nullable();
            $table->date('last_cover_check')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->unique(['artist_id', 'title']);
        });

        Schema::create('artists', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

The database has about 856000 plays with 33000 songs and 15000 artists.

At first I tried to use the models directly with eager loading of plays->songs->artist.

```php
return PlayResource::collection(Play::whereDate('date', $date)->get());
```

Using Insomnia this query on the REST API via Laravel takes 2.6s.
This is very slow, I think.

If I understand Laravel correctly it does to much DB queries:

- One query for plays
- another one for songs
- But than for every play/song a separate query for its artist (?)

So I tried to create a single JOIN query to have only one DB query:

```php
return DB::table('plays')
    ->leftJoin('songs', 'plays.song_id', '=', 'songs.id')
    ->leftJoin('artists', 'songs.artist_id', '=', 'artists.id')
    ->select('plays.*', 'songs.*', 'artists.*')
    ->whereDate('plays.date', $date)
    ->orderByDesc('plays.date')
    ->get();
```

This query is a little bit faster but still slow: 2.2s

The equivalent SQL query called directly on the DB is much faster:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM plays p
LEFT JOIN songs s ON p.song_id = s.id
LEFT JOIN artists a ON s.artist_id = a.id
WHERE DATE(p.date) = "2020-12-30"
ORDER BY p.date DESC;
```

-> 0.4s

Am I doing something wrong or is this typical overhead when using Laravel?

**EDIT1:**

OK, I've found `DB::getQueryLog()` (but that was not what I'm looking for). Now I know: Using three tables with chained eager loading causes only 3 DB queries. My first one is the slowest with nearly 400ms. The two queries only taking 1-2ms each.

I also found Lumen which should be faster than Laravel. So I tried it. My first query using models takes 1.4s now. Adding the JsonResources for output mappings it adds 0.3s -> 1.7s. All of this is still to slow in my opinion.

But I think this is the price I have to pay using a modern Framework. (My old playlist from 2006 doesn't use any frameworks).

**EDIT2:**
The first query can be significantly enhanced by:

1. adding an index on `date` column
2. and querying without using functions (`` DATE(`date`) `` or `->whereDate('date', ...)`) and instead using `->whereBetween('date', [$date, $date.' 23:59:59'])`
   Now the first query takes only 5ms (from 400ms before). And I'm 1.3s for the whole Lumen query.

The SQL queries are taking only <10ms now. So Lumen overhead is about 99%. Really bad. I'll search for further tuning potential.

**EDIT3**
I did now create this exact same REST API using Rust(actix_web, diesel) and the same request with same DB takes 16ms. It's crazy how slow these PHP framework is. I will now focus on Rust and drop PHP/Laravel/Lumen for the backend.

Comment: try to measure without converting to special collection. Just `Play::whereDate('date', $date)->with(['artist', 'song'])->get()`

Comment: Let's see the _generated_ SQL so we can spot the issue.

Comment: I've added a forced exception after the query to get Laravels debug screen. Under the Debug tab I can see the query before and how long it ran. With the JOIN query the generated query looks nearly the same as my written SQL query and it took 0.4s. So the overhead comes from Laravel. Not from the generated query.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the queries that are being launched by Laravel to the database by adding the following function to your app / providers / AppServiceProvider.php file:

```
public function boot(){
        if(env('APP_DEBUG')) {
            DB::listen(function($query) {
                File::append(
                    storage_path('/logs/query.log'),
                    $query->sql . ' [' . implode(', ', $query->bindings) . ']' . PHP_EOL
            );
            });
        }
    }
```

You will find the sql code of each query in the /storage/logs/query.log file that will be created.
This has helped me to understand and optimize query builder statements sometimes I have had similar problems.